# Ubuntu 14.04 Built in and External monitors not working together, only if 1 display active

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I have a laptop Asus N55SF with Nvidia GeForce GT555M.

I'm using LG monitor with HDMI.
When I installed 14.04 in first time it worked fine, both were enabled at the same time.

Then after some build update for nvidia driver at 331 - they just stop working together. How this happens:
- when I boot and see login screen - both are fine
- when I login I see 1 desktop stretched into 2 displays and can't click anywhere with mouse, because mouse position is wrong.

I can turn one monitor off with hardware buttons on my laptop and they works fine if one off them is off in the settings. But once I try to switch dual mode - all is stretched again and I need to wait the timeout to restore screens.

Does anyone had same problems?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution! Just found correct keywords for this in google. Big thanks to "bummi":

[nvidia-prime extended desktop stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587655/nvidia-prime-extended-desktop-stopped-working)

Will duplicate it here:

> Francisco Gouveia (fgouveia87) wrote on 2015-03-10:
>
> After days lost with replacing NVidia drivers and manually editing xorg.conf file, I finally found this!
>
> Rockwalrus (rockwalrus) solution works!
>
> - On CompizConfig Settings Manager, go to "General Options", then "Display Settings" and do the following:
> - Uncheck "Deteck Outputs"
>
> In the Outputs array, set the resolutions of each of your screens. The >numbers after the resolution "1920x1080+0+0" are the offset. It's important to add this offset according to your needs. I have two full HD screens, so I added the following configuration: 1920x1080+0+0 1920x1080+1920+0
>   The second output has an offset of 1920, because it is on the right side of the first output, which has a width of 1920.

You will need to install compiz settings manager as well:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz compiz-plugins compizconfig-settings-manager
```