# Multiple monitor on laptop incorrect resolution

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 with a monitor connected to HDMI port.
The graphic card is a NVIDIA GeForge  GTX 960M.

My problem is the output is correctly rendered just if I configure monitors in mirror screen mode.
When the mirror mode is not enable, both monitors render in incorrect resolution (icons, and windows are too big) and you cannot press the controles in screen, it seems the mouse input is shifted.

In not mirror mode, executing xrandr -q, outputs correct information:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm
 x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      74.98    59.89  
   ....
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+  59.93    40.01  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   ....
```

The output if I disable mirror mode.

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm
 x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   ....
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+  59.93    40.01  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   ....
```

The monitors appear to be in the correct resolution, but the "screen-0 " shows current 3840x1080.

I have updated my nvidia drivers (currently using NVIDIA binary driver -version 375.26)
[Ubuntu 16.04LTS extended display not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764142/ubuntu-16-04lts-extended-display-not-working)

Tried to delete xorg.conf as mention here
[Getting screen resolution correct with nvidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4253/getting-screen-resolution-correct-with-nvidia-drivers)

But didn't work.

Any suggestions in what's wrong?

EDIT:
Well my question is basically duplicated with these others, I keep to register what worked for me.

- [Ubuntu 16.04 nvidia drivers don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761136/ubuntu-16-04-nvidia-drivers-dont-work)
- [14.04 nvidia dual display (external+laptop) stretched display, offset desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/573465/14-04-nvidia-dual-display-externallaptop-stretched-display-offset-desktop)
- [Ubuntu 16.04 nvidia drivers don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761136/ubuntu-16-04-nvidia-drivers-dont-work)

Finally editing the compiz settings worked for me:

[nvidia-prime extended desktop stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587655/nvidia-prime-extended-desktop-stopped-working)

Answer (score 0):

Editing compiz settings worked!!!.

[image]