# Crackling sound when using headphones - 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, headphones

I'm experiencing an extremely unpleasant crackling noise whenever I try to use headphones. Even when I simply perform a sound test and "front left/right" is announced there is a great amount of crackling on the side that isn't being tested.

This has meant that my headphone jack is practically rendered useless because it is very uncomfortable to use headphones at any volume.

```
System: HP OMEN (15-ax003na)
Card: HDA Intel PCH
Chip: Realtek ALC295
```

Anyone else have this hardware or similar and experience this?

I've tried **both** of the solutions offered on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138266/distorted-and-choppy-audio) thread for 12.04 and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: did you try using another pair of headphones? headphones break very easily and don't last long. Perhaps your headphones are damaged. (http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/this-is-why-your-headphones-keep-breaking/)

Comment: If this is a desktop, did you try the front and the rear jacks?

Comment: I'm sure my headphones are fine, I've use more than one pair with this laptop and they both produce the same noise. I only have the one audio jack port, unfortunately.

Comment: There are actually 2 solutions listed at the [question you linked.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138266/distorted-and-choppy-audio) Did you try them both? Please [edit] your post to clarify so we don't waste time guessing what you've done. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Thanks for your advice, @ElderGeek. Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. You or a qualified professional might inspect the jack and where the jack is soldered to the board to see if this is a hardware problem caused by a damaged jack or a [cold solder joint](https://www.circuitspecialists.com/blog/soldering-repair-part1/)

Comment: I just find it unlikely that a brand new machine is faulty. If I run Windows via virtual machine and test the sound will this truly remove Ubuntu from the equation or is sound still being handled by the OS?

Comment: I disagree strongly about this being a duplicate. I have the exact same problem with my laptop which uses the same audio codec. I have tried multiple headphones and checked everything works fine in Windows. I have also bypassed pulseaudio to rule that out but the problem persists, when going direct through ALSA. There used to be problems with optimus/iommu and sound, so i tried running with intel_iommu=igfx_off to rule that out. There also appears to be a related bug suggesting there are other people struggling. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1648183

Comment: I had this weird issue too on my ZenBook 3 which has the same card. This happened I booted in Windows and then returned to Linux. Returning to Windows, shutting down properly and then booting with Linux fixed my problem. Turns out, Windows has managed to screw up my user experience even when I'm not using it.

Answer (score 0):

May be there is problem with your audio jack. Try some other headphones with your system if it is crackling again then there are chances that this problem is due to your audio jack.

Comment: I've tried other headphones and the problem remains. I did consider the audio jack being the problem but the laptop is brand new. I'm also having issues with the HDMI port (posted [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/856247/ubuntu-16-04-adding-external-monitor-doesnt-create-seperate-displays)) so this contributes to my doubts that the jack is faulty as I'm having compatibility issues elsewhere.