# A method to send Ubuntu's [16.04] audio over WiFi to an iOS [10.2] device?

Tags: 16.04, wireless, sound, streaming, iphone

I wanted to know whether there was currently a method to stream a system's audio to an iPhone via WiFi? I've noticed that this seems to be possible more easily for `Ubuntu -> Android` but didn't seem to come across any solutions offered for iOS.

Am I missing a server and app pair or some other solution?

*I'm still having audio issues via audio jack ([post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861360/crackling-sound-when-using-headphones-16-04)) so I'm looking for simple workarounds...*

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: Note that I have asked [this question over on Ask Different, the Apple-centric site, to try and gain an answer to your question from the iOS side of things](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270956/way-to-send-computer-audio-wirelessly-wifi-or-bluetooth-to-ios-device).  I cannot guarantee they'll give Linux compatible solutions, if any solutions, but we'll see.

Comment: You need a DLNA or Chromecast **receiver** app for iOS, which I believe do exist. Then use [pulseaudio-dlna](http://askubuntu.com/a/567075/3940) on your Ubuntu box. Or altenatively run Icecast on Ubuntu for an Internet radio stream: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network

Comment: Has anyone successfully used a *specific* DLNA/Chromecast/UPnP iOS app with pulseaudio-dlna? I’ve just tried ~10 different ones, none of them were discovered by pulseaudio-dlna, so troubleshooting with a known-working app would be a great sanity check.