# Cracking and popping sound from left side of headphone on Front Left/Right sound test

Tags: 16.04, sound, hp, audio-jack

I have exactly the same problem as
1. [Crackling sound when using headphones - 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861360/crackling-sound-when-using-headphones-16-04)
However this question is marked as duplicate of
2. [Distorted and Choppy Audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138266/distorted-and-choppy-audio)

I have exactly the problem.

And the comments on the following links shows that the problem is common for audio chip `Realtek ALC295`
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1648183
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195457

and it seems that it is a problem in kernel.

The result of `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec` is

```
Codec: Realtek ALC295
Codec: Intel Kabylake HDMI
```

and as you can see that it uses the same sound chip as appeared on the first link. My laptop is also brand new like it appeared on the first link. I suspect that it is a software problem, not a hardware problem.

I tried both of the solutions in the second link (which is from 4 years ago!) but none worked.

relevant output from `lspci -v` is

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 81a9
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 292
    Memory at b1228000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b1210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

and kernel information

```
Linux computername 4.10.0-20-generic #22~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 17:43:29 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I think this problem is NOT a duplicate of the second link (although it technically is a duplicate of the first link).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [post by Robert Joynt](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1648183/comments/17) in the [Crackling and popping sound when using headphones](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1648183) Launchpad bug report solves the issue. I'm quoting the post below (code formatting my own):

> I've managed to
> fix this problem on my machine (HP Omen 15 running Ubuntu 17.04 using
> codec for Realtek ALC295 sound device). To fix the problem, I can do
> the following:
>
> Install `alsa-tools` if not installed:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install alsa-tools
> ```
>
> Create and save a script in `/usr/local/bin`:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash 
> hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 SET_COEF_INDEX 0x67
> hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 SET_PROC_COEF 0x3000
> ```
>
> Run the script as root in a terminal to immediately fix the problem.
>
> To run the script on startup, use `cron` with the `@reboot` command:
>
> ```
> sudo crontab -e
> ```
>
> and then add line in `crontab`:
>
> ```
> @reboot [full path to script]
> ```
>
> To run script on resume from suspend, copy the script to
> `/lib/systemd/system-sleep`
>
> For more technical details regarding this fix, see
> https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195457

Comment: Didn't work for me :-( I also tried it with `hwC1D0` (just guessing), and didn't work too. My workaround: In sound settings, move the balance a little to the right ;-)

Comment: sudo apt install alsa-tools is life saving:)

Comment: after installing also I changed the built in Audio profile to analog surrounding

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem with my HP Pavilion i7-7500U running Xubuntu 16.04.2 LTS on 4.8.15-040815-generic kernel. It has the same sound device as you, Realtek ALC295.

This is clearly demonstrated by muting the left output channel while playing something - there appears to be a distinct crackling noise leaking through from the right channel to the left, despite being muted.

Looking through several forums, one of the recommendations provided was to boot into Windows 10 with headphones not plugged in, restart from the login screen and boot into [X]ubuntu - then plug in your headphones once you've logged in.

Since doing this I've had no problems - but I appear to have to do this for every restart.

While this isn't a permanent fix, out of courtesy I thought I would share my findings.

Comment: Thank you, I am regretting deleting windows for the first time...
I hope it gets fixed soon.

Comment: I updated my answer below. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have found quite dummy solution (HP Omen). It's requires Windows and Ubuntu installed on notebook (dualboot):

1) Start Windows, insert headphones, ensure that they are enabled.
 2) Reboot notebook without headphones ejecting, select Ubuntu instead of.
 3) Enjoy, noise will be absent