# Why running some command is giving me "Permission denied"?

Tags: sound, permissions

I've just installed ubuntu and my earphones are having weird pop noices. Other people had this problem and they solved it. But when I copy their command and try to run it gives me "Permission denied". What should I do?

The source commands " [Cracking and popping sound from left side of headphone on Front Left/Right sound test](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910221/cracking-and-popping-sound-from-left-side-of-headphone-on-front-left-right-sound?newreg=3eda92f472774d4e8477e9b81747a5af) ".

Comment: Please include the exact commands you ran and the exact output you got as [text with code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) in this post

Comment: In addition, it is difficult to see in your link which commands you exactly ran.

Comment: This ^^^ and very likely the script posted as and answer in your link WON'T help at all.

Comment: Okay my bad, I'll do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/916516) you seem to be referring to don't make clear that you also need to give that script you create in `/usr/local/bin` execute permissions before *anyone* is allowed to run it.

Only then can you run the script with `sudo`.

First do this with the command:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/FILENAME
```