# Duplicate screen on Nvidia not working

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg, display-resolution

I have an issue with multi-screen on my new computer with Ubuntu 16.04.

My new computer is a Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming. http://www.dell.com/fr/p/inspiron-15-7567-laptop/pd?oc=cn56705&model_id=inspiron-15-7567-laptop

I install the proprietary driver for my nvidia graphic card

I can switch between my intel card and my nvidia card.

The problem is when I want to connect an other screen. First it is only work when the Nvidia card is selected not the intel one but fine maybe that normal.

But now with the Nvidia card all work grate in mirror mode but when I want to duplicate screen both displays are going to wrong resolution with no mouse control on my primary screen and strange mouse control on duplicate screen (can't make correct screen shot but you can imagine what is a screen with a clompletly wrong resolution.

I have searched a lot for what going on and the only think I have found is that my built in screen have no settings in nvidia settings.

Like I can only post 2 link here is a link to all the screenshot :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDWax.jpg

In this page I have found I see both configuration and not one :

help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaMultiMonitors (can't put a link her sorry)

Do you have any idea of what is wrong with my computer ?

Other screen shot informations and Xorg.conf and Xorg.0.log:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

pastebin.com/D4ckLAY3 (can't make a link sorry)

Comment: I have no experience with multiple video-cards in a system, but I suggest you look at `man xrandr` (or Google for examples) to read/change screen resolutions.

Comment: @adrien have you find a solution for this problem? I have the same issue with my  Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming

Comment: Currently, only this workaround works [https://askubuntu.com/a/915265/170439](https://askubuntu.com/a/915265/170439)

Comment: i think Mirroring and Duplicate screen are the same thing. what do you mean duplicate screen is going to wrong resolution?
multi-monitor either works in Mirror mode or extended mode. and there's a single checkbox to toggle that. Maybe after you toggle off the mirror checkbox, the resolution are not setting properly. you can set them manually again.

Comment: @WillemK I suppose xrandr could make thins work I tried it at first with no result I think i just used badly him (don't remember exactly the command but I think it's becaus I would tried to configure only hdmi output and not both screen)

Comment: @user170439 thank you VERY Much your work around is working !!! not perfect because you need to change every time it's a different screen but it's working and that cool !

Comment: @astrob0t thank for the reply, I was talking about extended screen. It's because  the built in display is connected to intel iGPU so it make some wrong thing. Can't explain much here see other response on the link of user170439 if you are curious.

Comment: @AdrienRobotLabo: Using `xrandr` is not so difficult. If you just type xrandr, if will show you: the Virtual screen name(usually Screen 0 and its resolutions);  the detected monitors: for example HDMI-1, VGA-1, etc and if they are connected or not. In your system I would expect 2 connected monitors. Lets say HDMI-1 and VGA-1. To turn VGA-1 monitor off: `xrandr --output VGA-1 off`. To turn it on, assuming it is left of HDMI-1: `xrandr --output VGA-1 --left-of HDMI-1 --auto`. You can swap the monitor names and use --right-of to play with HDMI-1... or whatever names xrandr reported at first.

Comment: Example to change the resolution of the monitors: `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --output VGA-1 --mode 1440x900`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no expirence with duel graphics cards, but my computer did a wrong resolution on second monitor when i did mirror and the close window and activities menue were unacessable.

to fix it, i put it on single display on the secondary monitor, as my computer's resolution was non-native to the tv, it let me choose the tv's resolution when it only displayed there. i use an intel graphics card btw.

if your desktop icons only show on 1, you may have it on extend display.

as for the intel never working, try rebooting with the graphics card you want on extended display selected, then do the same when you want to switch back. it may make it primary for that boot session, no garentee on this part as i only have a one graphic card laptop